# Question up-voting is not working from my code?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, android, voting

I am trying to upvote a question using the Stack Exchange API in android, via the `/2.2/questions/{questionID}/upvote` route.

But in the log, it's just showing something like:

> org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@33b2c539

API link for upvote a question is https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question

When I try it from [the API doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question) it works, but not from my code.

```
String url= "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+questionId+"/upvote";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient ();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost (url.toString () ); 

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair> (2);

nameValuePair.add (new BasicNameValuePair ("key", key) );
nameValuePair.add (new BasicNameValuePair ("access_token", accessToken) );

try {
        httpPost.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity (nameValuePair) );
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
}
// making request

try {
       response = httpClient.execute (httpPost);
        Log.d ("Http Post Response:", response.toString () );
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with `HttpClient` but the problem does not seem to be caused by your code. Probably it is the lack of required parameters that causes problem. When I called this function in C#, I passed following parameters in order to make it work. I am not sure about "preview" parameter but I believe the `site` parameter is a must.

```
Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
parameters.Add("key", APPLICATION_KEY);
parameters.Add("access_token", AccessToken);
parameters.Add("site", SiteApiParameter);
parameters.Add("filter", filter);
parameters.Add("preview", "false");
```

Comment: Yes, `site` is required -- on almost all API calls.   `preview` should be set to true for development and testing.