# Posting question using StackExchange API

Tags: support

I created one app to post questions to Stack Exchange Websites. While checking in doc page of my application, i.e., https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question, the question is posted. If I do it repeatedly, my account would be suspended. Is there any test Stack Exchange website to check this?

Also, if I am checking my application, then posting many questions also would be a problem. So, do we have a solution for this?

Comment: For testing purposes, you can set preview parameter to true so your question will not be written to StackExchange database.

Comment: Can you post this as answer to the question? I checked it by repeatedly running the same function. Its not giving me any error that this question is already asked. Although, it doesn't give all the parameters as requested, like `question_id`. Also, give [reference](http://stackapps.com/questions/6284/question-up-voting-is-not-working-from-my-code#comment13489_6290).

Comment: OK I added this as an answer. This question was basically the same as your other question but asked from a different perspective :) So although the answer is a dublicate the question is not IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is the same to your other question about [preview parameter](https://stackapps.com/questions/6420/role-of-preview-in-questions-add).

As @BrockAdams mentioned in [a comment to one of my questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/6284/question-up-voting-is-not-working-from-my-code#comment13489_6290) previously, you need to set preview parameter to true while testing write API calls.

Please check the [other answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/6420/role-of-preview-in-questions-add/6435#6435) for more information.

Comment: While posting this question, I wasn't knowing that I will be posting two question having the same answer.

Comment: Yes this is asked from a different perspective :) The answers being the same is by chance. Hope the answer helps.

Comment: thanks birkan!! I have been trying for so long. finally i could post.