# Role of "preview" in "/questions/add"

Tags: support

To post questions using Stack Exchange API, I am using [/questions/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question). What does parameter `preview` do, i.e., if we set it to true/false, what behaviour would it give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [a comment of @BrockAdams to one of my answers](https://stackapps.com/questions/6284/question-up-voting-is-not-working-from-my-code#comment13489_6290), the preview parameter is used for development and testing purposes.

If you set it to true, your request will only simulate whether it is a valid request or not and will not change anything on the site.